# When adding buttons to the tinyMCE editor, how do I make them wrap to the next line and/or display in the "Kitchen Sink" area?

Tags: filters, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm successfully adding buttons to the TinyMCE editor in Wordpress, but the problem is they all show up to the right of the Kitchen Sink button and I have so many that I need them to display on a new line. How do I make the buttons wrap to the next line and/or create a new row for my custom buttons? Here is my code:

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.boxlight', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addButton('boxlight', {
            title : 'Add a light content box',
            image : url+'/images/box-light.png',
            theme_advanced_buttons3_add : 'boxlight',
            onclick : function() {
                 ed.selection.setContent('[box_light]' + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/box_light]');

            }
        });
    },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('boxlight', tinymce.plugins.boxlight);
```

That code just adds the buttons to the main TinyMCE toolbar and I can't figure out how to add the buttons to a new toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you're also adding a filter `mce_buttons` to add in the button to, something like..

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'add_my_tinymce_buttons' );

function add_my_tinymce_buttons( $items ) {
    $items[] = 'your-button';
    return $items;
}
```

Just change the filter to hook onto `mce_buttons_2` instead, and the button will appear on the second row , eg..

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'add_my_tinymce_buttons' );
```

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! Wish I had enough rep to vote up your answer since it was so clear and helpful :)

Comment: No hurry on the rep, just happy to provide an answer and you're welcome.. ;)